Error in code even though logic is correct for finding maximum subarray sum
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int maxSubArray(vector<int>nums) {
    int sum=0; int maxsum=INT_MIN;int i=-1;
    while(i++< nums.size()){           
        if(i<nums.size()) sum+=nums[i];
        maxsum=max(sum,maxsum);
        if(sum<0) sum=0;
    }
    return maxsum;
}
int main() {
vector<int>arr{-2,1,-3,4,-1,2,1,-5,4};
cout<<maxSubArray(arr);
    return 0;
}

This is my code to find find the subarray with the largest sum, and return its sum.
For the test case that I have used:
nums = [-2,1,-3,4,-1,2,1,-5,4]
The expected answer should be = 6 (The subarray [4,-1,2,1] has the largest sum 6)
But my code gives me output = -2147483648.
I specifically added a check again at this line for the case when i= nums.size()-1 or at the "n-1"th index.
To me my code seems logicaly correct. But I am not able to pin-point why it's not giving the right output.

Side notes: (1) Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>? (2) What's the problem with "using namespace std;"?.

Also see: What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?.

Another side note: instead of passing arr by value, you can pass it by const& to save the unneeded copy.

while(i++< nums.size()) is problematic: nums.size() is unsigned, and so i is also converted to unsigned. being -1 it turns into a very large integer and so the loop never executes.

Typo change i++ to ++i   ? Also see dupe: Post-increment and Pre-increment concept?

My question is why can't i++ work instead of ++i ? The only problem I see with it is that the loop runs 1 more iteration extra , and since the value of i is already incremented before executing the loop body , how will it change the answer in any way?
on the last iteration , when i =n-1 , the second check for i<nums.size() inside the loop will ensure that we don't add extra values.

Side note: How to debug small programs

Your first mistake, doing competitive coding before you learned how to use C++ properly. You should learn C++ from a good source first. E.g. learncpp.com, then learn how to use cppreference.com (a lot of containers/algorithms are ready for use).  By learning C++ first you will avoid a lot of mistakes (like using the wrong include files, not passing collections by reference etc). Or if you plan only doing "puzzle" solving part of competitive coding,Python is an easier language to begin with.

INT_MIN is "C", use std::numeric_limits<int>::min(),

It is because you have i++ which evaluates i < nums.size() first and then increases the itself. So you have to first increment it as you have initialized i = -1. Hence it will solve the problem
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int maxSubArray(vector<int> nums) {
    int sum = 0;
    int maxsum = INT_MIN;
    int i = -1;
    
    while (++i < nums.size()) {
        if (i < nums.size()) sum += nums[i];
        maxsum = max(sum, maxsum);
        if (sum < 0) sum = 0;
    }
    return maxsum;
}

int main() {
    vector<int> arr{-2, 1, -3, 4, -1, 2, 1, -5, 4};
    cout << maxSubArray(arr);
    return 0;
}


but with my current code , since i is inititally -1 , it will be incremented to 0 after the check in the loop condition, since it's a post increment. So the loop will run n+1 times rather than n. But how does this affect the answer in any way? Since i is already incremented to 0 by the time the loop body executes right?

No as per your current implementation it will run only n-1 times. For better understand try to run your code with only one array element
